# Simulating periodic boundary condition with long_range interaction

Tags: boundary-conditions, simulation

Consider 2 particles in a 2D plane. There is a long-range interaction between two particles:
$$f (r_i-r_j)= \frac{\vec{r_i} - \vec{r_j}}{|r_i-r_j|^3}$$
$$\vec{r_i} =(x_i,y_i)$$

$r_i$ determines the position of particle number $i$ in the plane. Knowing position of particles in the 2D plane and also knowing that distances of particles is more than a threshold $r_0$ (so $f$ do not get infinite), how can one find $f_{tot}$ in the position of all particles in a periodic boundary condition simulation?

$f_{tot} $ is sum of effect of images of $j$ particle in f:

$$f_{tot}(\vec{r_i})= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg ( \frac{(x_i - x_j + n L,0)}{|y_i - y_j + n L|^3} \bigg) +  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg ( \frac{(0,y_i - y_j + n L)}{|y_i - y_j + n L|^3} \bigg)$$

in above relation, r_i and r_j are known and n is an integer number which changes from -infinity to infinity

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! You need to add a lot more details to your question -- for example, what is $f_{tot}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I have added details, is it clear now? @ChristianClason

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to calculat f_tot @nicoguaro

Comment: You  already have an expression for it, why not using it?

Comment: Because I can not find f_tot in simulation @nicoguaro

Comment: You probably want to evalute that sum in Fourier space.  See [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.88.063308) for an overview of methods to evaluate such long-range interactions.

Comment: The paper you introduced is related to long-range interactions as 1/r. in my case, interaction is 1/r^2 @HenriMenke